# finding the probability to get a diploma

Tags: probability

For getting a diploma a person needs to go to $3$ interviews at $3$ teachers: $A,B,C$.

In each interview a teacher can give a positive opinion or negative opinion.

The person will go to interview at each of the teachers and after that they ($A,B,C)$ will meet and compare their opinions about that person.

- The probability that teacher $A$ will give a positive opinion is $0.75$.
- The probability that teacher $B$ will agree with the opinion of teacher $A$ is $\frac{2}{3}$.
- The probability that teacher $C$ will agree with the opinion of teacher $A$ is $0.25$.

The person will get the diploma only if at least $2$ of the teachers gave him a positive opinion.

> Given that teacher $B$ gave the person a positive opinion, what is the probability that the person didn't get the diploma?

**My Attempt**: i tried to find the probability for the person to get a diploma and i got $\frac{5}{8}$ but i don't know how to continue.

**The answer** is $\frac{1}{28}$ but i don't know why.

Comment: Did you have a kind of process or only the "raw" answer?

Comment: just the final answer.

Comment: @Martigan I guess they did: $\frac{1}{3} \times  \frac{1}{4} \times \frac{1}{4}: \frac{7}{12}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map the entire sample-space:

- $P(    {A}\wedge    {B}\wedge    {C})=\frac34\cdot\frac23\cdot\frac14$
- $P(    {A}\wedge    {B}\wedge\neg{C})=\frac34\cdot\frac23\cdot\frac34$
- $P(    {A}\wedge\neg{B}\wedge    {C})=\frac34\cdot\frac13\cdot\frac14$
- $P(    {A}\wedge\neg{B}\wedge\neg{C})=\frac34\cdot\frac13\cdot\frac34$
- $P(\neg{A}\wedge    {B}\wedge    {C})=\frac14\cdot\frac13\cdot\frac34$
- $P(\neg{A}\wedge    {B}\wedge\neg{C})=\frac14\cdot\frac13\cdot\frac14$
- $P(\neg{A}\wedge\neg{B}\wedge    {C})=\frac14\cdot\frac23\cdot\frac34$
- $P(\neg{A}\wedge\neg{B}\wedge\neg{C})=\frac14\cdot\frac23\cdot\frac14$

Sum up the probabilities of the given event (a positive opinion made by $B$):

- $P(    {A}\wedge    {B}\wedge    {C})=\frac34\cdot\frac23\cdot\frac14$
- $P(    {A}\wedge    {B}\wedge\neg{C})=\frac34\cdot\frac23\cdot\frac34$
- $P(\neg{A}\wedge    {B}\wedge    {C})=\frac14\cdot\frac13\cdot\frac34$
- $P(\neg{A}\wedge    {B}\wedge\neg{C})=\frac14\cdot\frac13\cdot\frac14$

Sum up the probabilities of the desired event (a positive opinion made **only** by $B$):

- $P(\neg{A}\wedge    {B}\wedge\neg{C})=\frac14\cdot\frac13\cdot\frac14$

Divide the latter by the former in order to calculate the conditional probability: $\dfrac{\frac{1}{48}}{\frac{28}{48}}=\frac{1}{28}$

Answer (score 0):

Since you know that B gave a positive opinion, you need to know whether A gave a positive opinion as well, or if not, whether C gave a positive opinion.

B agreeing with the opinion of A is the same as A agreeing with the opinion of B. So A has a $\frac 13$ probability of having given a negative opinion.

If they gave a negative one ($\frac 13$ probability), then C will give a negative opinion as well $\frac 14$ of the time.

Therefore, the probability that at the person had not the diploma is $\frac 13 \times \frac 14= \frac{1}{12}$.

Comment: i'm not fully understand the calculation. in my notebook it said that the answer is $\frac{1}{28}$ but i don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bayes's Law symbolically, but it may be easier to just enumerate the possibilities in plain English.  $B$ gives a positive response when either $A$ gives a positive response and $B$ agrees (with probability $(3/4)(2/3) = 1/2$), or when $A$ gives a negative response and $B$ disagrees (with probability $(1/4)(1/3) = 1/12$).  The probability that $B$ is positive is therefore $1/2+1/12 = 7/12$.

On the other hand, with $B$ positive, the only way the student fails to receive the diploma is if $A$ is negative, $B$ disagrees, and $C$ agrees (with $A$).  That happens with probability $(1/4)(1/3)(1/4) = 1/48$.

Thus the probability that the student fails to receive a diploma, given that $B$ was positive, is $1/48$ divided by $7/12$, or $1/28$.

ETA: Symbolically:

$$
\begin{align}
P(\text{no diploma} \mid \text{$B$ positive})
    & = \frac{P(\text{$B$ positive, no diploma})}{P(\text{$B$ positive})} \\
    & = \frac{P(\text{$A$ negative, $B$ positive, $C$ negative})}
             {P(\text{$A$ positive, $B$ agrees with $A$}) +
              P(\text{$A$ negative, $B$ disagrees with $A$})} \\
    & = \frac{P(\text{$A$ negative, $B$ disagrees with $A$, $C$ agrees with $A$})}
             {P(\text{$A$ positive, $B$ agrees with $A$}) +
              P(\text{$A$ negative, $B$ disagrees with $A$})} \\
    & = \frac{(1/4)(1/3)(1/4)}{(3/4)(2/3)+(1/4)(1/3)} \\
    & = \frac{1/48}{7/12} = \frac{1}{28}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: I have a question that might be stupid. Is there a difference between: "What is the probability that the student did not get the diploma with a positive opinion from the professor B?" and "You learn that the professor B gave a positive opinion, what is the probability that the student do not get the diploma?"...

Comment: I'd say the second formulation is more clearly a conditional probability: *Given* that $B$ gave a positive opinion, what is the probability of not receiving a diploma?  Whereas the first formulation is hazier as to whether it's conditional or joint: It might be the same sense as the other, but it might also be interpreted as, what is the probability that the student did not receive a diploma *in addition to* (as opposed to, assuming) $B$ was positive?

Comment: Symbolically, we denote a conditional probability as $P(A \mid B)$, meaning the probability that $A$ is true, given that $B$ is true, and we denote a joint probability as $P(A, B)$, meaning the probability that both $A$ and $B$ are true.  They are related by $P(A \mid B) = P(A, B)/P(B)$.

Comment: B can't disagree though.

Comment: $B$ can't disagree with *what*?